# ASP.NET Core 5 Fastest way to search a category and child categories

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, parent-child, recursive-query

I am looking for the fastest way of searching for product in a category and its child categories. Each product has only 1 category, but when I search in a category all sub-cats should be searched

I found 3 general ways
1- placing product category tree in each product and search in this field

```
Class Product{
    Other fields {set;get;}
    string CategoryTree {set;get;} "\2\17\234\"        // cat 234 is child of 17 and 17 is child of 2   
}
```

2- place CategoryId in Product table and CategoryTree to each category, then search in product in which its category contain "\x\"

```
Class Product{
    Other fields {set;get;}
    int CategoryId {set;get;}  
}
Class Category{
    Other fields {set;get;}
    string ParentTree {set;get;}  "\2\17\239\"
}
```

3- Using Recursive searching in categories **Fails due to serious speed issue**

```
        public static IEnumerable<T> Ascendants<T>(this T root, Func<T, T> parentSelector)
        {
            var stack = new Stack<T>(new[] { root });
            while (stack.Any() && stack != null)
            {
                T next = stack.Pop();
                yield return next;

                if (parentSelector(next) != null)
                    stack.Push(parentSelector(next));

            }
        }

        public List<Category> GetParents()
        {

            return this.Ascendants(t => t.ParentCategory).ToList();

        }
```

**Consider millions of products and thousands of categories.**

What would be the best solution friends? is **HierarchyID** helping?

Comment: With 1st and 2nd approaches consider what you will need to if update to category tree is needed. For the 3d one - have you tried recursive sql queries (recursively finding all categories in the tree should be that slow)? Another approach is to have a view which will flatten all the categories somehow (like having root category set up).

Comment: @GuruStron in 1-2 I should update products/categories if needed, about flatten categories view, would you mind letting me know about that, I haven't read about it.

Comment: Yes, you will need to update "millions of products" in the 1st case, which is usually not a good thing. And thousands of categories in the second case, which is much better but can be not very good also. Can you please show your "Recursive searching" attempt? What database are you using?

Comment: @GuruStron I added my recursive code to the code, plz check it